# Error converting selected date - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I am making a filter between two dates, **Start date** and **End date**, the filter works perfect, it brings the data but it does not bring the complete data and it is because when selecting the dates and converting them to the format, it converts them but one day remains.

This way I am converting the dates:

```
 FiltrarPorFechas(incial, final) {
    this.ListaUsuarios = [];
    const IniDate = new Date(incial);
    const EndDate = new Date(final);
}
```

associate an image with debug and conversion:

[image]

As shown in the image, the initial and final dates arrive at the method thus **"2019-07-10"** and **"2019-07-31"** but when I try to convert them it puts them one day less as shown in the image.

I have tried to use **`moment`** **`formatDate`** and it does not work, I do not understand why and I do not want to add one day.

Somebody could help me ?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I want them to arrive as I select them, if I select 10, when I convert it, it's 10 not 9

Comment: can you try `moment(new Date(incial)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')` ?

Comment: give me a second I do the test

Comment: I suspect its something with the timezone, lets see,

Comment: I have a problem with this since it converts it to string and I can't compare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199544/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-francisco-j-blanco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be potentially having an issue with Timezone. You could reset the time to `00:00:00` either using `moment.js` or from a normal `Date()` object.

Now, since your aim is to compare the times, you can use the `diff()` available from `moment.js` to achieve this. Please find the sample code below

```js
(function() {
  initial = '2019-07-09';
  initial_formatted = moment(new Date(`${initial} 00:00:00`));
  final = '2019-07-31';
  final_formatterd = moment(new Date(`${final} 00:00:00`));
  console.log(initial_formatted.diff(final_formatterd, 'days'));

  // moment(new Date(`${incial} 00:00:00`)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**More info**

[Moment diff()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

[Date Object set() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp)